# CSS Modules using Angular 2 without inline templates

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, css-modules

I am trying to get CSS Modules working with Angular 2 without using inline templates. The official style guide also suggests not to use inline templates when you have more than 3 lines of markup. So my idea was to use a combination of `lodash-templates` and `file-loader` but I am not sure if the output of the `lodash-template-loader` is accepted by the `file-loader`. This is how I want my component to look like:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

var styles = require('./foo.css');

@Component({
    'selector': 'my-component',
    'templateUrl': require('./foo.html')
})
export class MyComponent {

}
```

I know this won't work because the output of the `lodash-template-loader`, for example the [ejs-loader](https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader) is a function which has to be called with the data that will be used to compile the template.
I want to use the `styles` within my template then like:

```
<div class="<%= styles.root %>"></div>
```

So basically I want to compile this usingh `ejs-loader` for example and then pipe it to the `file-loader` so that I get separate html files. I have no idea how to achieve this. I mean the above is just an idea but I don't know how to compile the template and then pipe it into the `file-loader` since this won't work with just the `require` statement. Any ideas?

According to the documentation of the `ejs-loader` I have to do the following to compile the template:

```
var template = require("ejs!./foo.html");
template(styles);
```

I suppose that the `template` function then returns the template as a string. But how do I know create a separate html out of it? Do I even need the `file-loader`?

**EDIT**

So probably a solution could be to implement a custom loader that takes the file and the styles object. The loader then returns an output that can be passed to the `file-loader`. The problem here ist, how do I pass the styles object to the loader? And how to convert the template string to a format that the `filer-loader` can read?

Comment: you should do something similar to this: `'template': require('./foo.html')`, similar for css.. please note its template and not templateUrl

Comment: @entre Thats something I dont want. I don't want inline templates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in an Angular 8 application (it's possible to do it in Angular 7 or higher too).

My solution was customize the build (thanks to [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack)) and use [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules).

[postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) hash all the styles, then [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) replaces the class names on the html files by the hashed class names.

I documented my solution here:

- Live Demo: https://angular-css-modules.herokuapp.com/
- Github Repo: https://github.com/gquinteros93/angular-css-modules
- Article with the step by step: https://indepth.dev/angular-css-modules/